# PDFCROP fails at GHOSTSCRIPT execution

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, ghostscript, miktex

I've got following error on my windows machine (Windows 10 Enterprise, 64-bit) using **PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06**:

```
!!! Error: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs' (No such file or directory/The system cannot find the file specified)!
```

Here's the --debug info.

```
pdfcrop --debug --margins "1 1 1 1" "C:\test.pdf" "C:\test.pdf"
PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.

PDFCROP 1.40, 2020/06/06 - Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Heiko Oberdiek, Oberdiek Package Support Group.
* Restricted mode: disabled
* Option `pdfversion': auto
* Perl executable: C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
* Perl version: v5.32.1
* Pointer size: 8
* Pipe support: yes
* Fork support: no
* OS name: MSWin32
* Arch name: MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
* System: miktex
* Not found (mgs): mgs.exe
* Found (mgs): C:\Users\Buckel\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe
* Autodetected ghostscript command: mgs
* Input file: test.pdf
* Output file: test.pdf
* Margins: 1 1 1 1
* PDF header: %PDF-1.7
* Using PDF version: 1.7
* Running ghostscript for BoundingBox calculation ...
* Ghostscript call: mgs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f test.pdf
* Cleanup
* Temporary files: tmp-pdfcrop-8160.tex
!!! Error: Cannot call ghostscript `mgs' (No such file or directory/The system cannot find the file specified)!
```

I've installed pdfcrop via miktex, latest version (4.8), use Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.32.1.1-64bit and Ghostscript 9.56.1, 64-bit (2022-04-04).

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!
Tobias

---

In addition, I've completely removed my setup, i.e. desinstalled Miktex and Ghostscript and re-installed with 1) Ghostscript 9.52 (64-bit, older Version from 2020) and 2) Miktext 4.8 (same as before). **Problem still exists.**

Further looking into it i've tried to call pdfcrop including --gscmd gswin64c, i.e. <pdfcrop --debug --gscmd gswin64 --margins "1 1 1 1" "input_file.pdf" "output_file.pdf">. **Problem still exists.**

I've tried to set MIKTEX_PREFERMIKTEXGHOSTSCRIPT=false according to [MiKTeX/miktex-packaging#218 (comment)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636379/override-miktex-bundled-ghostscript-with-a-separate-installation). **Problem still exists.**

I've checked to have all required paths in my %PATH% env. variable as well, i.e. C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin and C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\

A manual call of the last executed command (according to returned debug information) <mgs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f test.pdf> however, works and returns the bounding box information.

Comment: @KJ, sorry - that's a bit to cryptic for me, can you please explain your thought in more detail?

Comment: Thanks, now i got it ... well it is located where you assumed (according to the command line call "where /r %localappdata% mgs*") ...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe
I will try to see if the miktex gs version somehow behaves differently as I might assume since I assumed orig. gs in my scripting back then.

However, I still don't get why I can't motivate pdfcrop to use the orig. gs exe (gswin64c)...

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/